# Avoiding Censoring in Survival Analysis?

Tags: regression, survival

Suppose there is a system in which:

- Individuals are measured only at discrete time points (e.g. blood pressure is measured once every year)
- These individuals have the ability to transition between "multiple states" (e.g. disease free, disease stage 1, disease stage 2, death by disease of interest , death by comorbidity, lost to follow up etc.) until one of the absorbing states is reached or the period of study is over
- The goal of the analysis is to understand what how different cohorts of patients and patient characteristics contribute to the transitions between these states.

In classical Survival Analysis, we often encounter observations that are "censored" (e.g. Right Censored, Left Censored, Interval Censored). I have read that depending on the complexity of the situation, censoring can be difficult to handle - as a matter of fact, the likelihood function in survival regression models have to be adjusted to incorporate censoring and can become more difficult so solve sometimes.

Recently, I have been learning more about "Multi-State Models", in which patients have the ability to transition back-and-forth between "multiple states", and we can study how evolving patient characteristics influence the probability of a specific state transitioning behavior.

**This brings me to my question:** Suppose I decide to use a "Multi-State Model" for the problem that I described -and in this problem, I decide to treat "censoring" (e.g. "temporary absence", "missed medical appointment") as a "State" within this model - by doing this, in some way am I effectively "avoiding" dealing with censoring directly? By doing this, I am now treating censoring as a "State" and can allow multiple entries/exits from/to this "State".  Is it possible that in certain applications, what is typically considered as "censoring" (e.g. drop out from medical study) could be re-classified as a "State"?

Is this correct?

Thanks!

Note: Suppose I have a model with the following states. As an example, let's say that an individual can exit the study - but can also re-enter the study. And even if the individual has exited the study, we can still find out if and when the individual has died:

[image]

In traditional Survival Analysis, "Exit the Study" would have likely been considered as "Censoring" - but in a Multi State Model, could we just consider this as another "state"?

Comment: I've noticed that you often add bounties to your questions requesting "answers from a reputable source." For instance, all 10 of the most recent bounties you've offered have requested authoritative references. I think you would be more likely to get the answers you're looking for if you specifically requested an answer from an reputable source in the body of the question when you first post it, instead of posting a question, getting an answer, and then offering a bounty stating that you'd like references.

Answer (score 2):

The point of censoring is that it's a property of your data collection, not of the process you're trying to model.

To take a simple example: over a year you recruit people and you randomise them to get treatment or control and follow them up until the end of the year.  You want to estimate how many people are alive at six months after treatment; this is complicated because some of the people haven't yet reached six months after treatment. That's right-censoring.  The key point is that you want to estimate the survival distribution for **all the people**, and it's just a nuisance that you don't have six months of data for all of them. People who die after they are censored **really die**, even though you don't observe it. You're trying to estimate what would happen in the absence of censoring; what happens in the real world. That's why there are strong assumptions needed about censoring.

With multistate models, the states are all real and part of what you're modelling.  If someone's data is censored, and they die without being observed, that's not a death from the viewpoint of your model. Only observed state transitions matter. The big advantage of multistate models is the same as their big disadvantage: they don't even try to estimate what would happen in the absence of a particular state, so they don't need as strong assumptions.

So, usually if you have censoring you really don't want a multistate model, you want censoring.  Right censoring is not actually that hard to handle even for semiparametric and non-parametric analyses. Left censoring and interval censoring are reasonably straightforward for parametric models. The likelihood is different, but it's different in well-understood ways.

Multistate models are useful when you actually want to model just the observable state transitions. They're also useful for competing-risk problems where you might **want to** model the distribution of one cause of death in the absence of another, but you can't, because you don't have those data.  They're not a good substitute for modelling censoring.

Comment: @ Thomas Lumley: Thank you for your answer! So just to clarify - in general this is not a good idea. But is it possible that in certain applications, what is typically considered as "censoring" (e.g. drop out from medical study) could be re-classified as a "State"?

Answer (score 2):

Censoring in a multi-state model is just that a patient was in some state at the end of the observation time you have on the patient. You kind of know that unless it's death, the patient will transition at least once more after you stopped observing the patient. So, really, you have in no way got rid of censoring. A lot of multi-state models tend to use survival (i.e. = staying in the current state) processes for the transitions between states over time for that reason.

The main reason to use a multi-state model (vs. a traditional survival model) is that you are modeling a situation with multiple states that matter (rather than two states in survival/time-to-event analysis: no event yet and at least one event) including situations where you can repeatedly end up in the same state.